# How to set footer as last element in all the websites

Tags: html, css

Please check ***[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNG3Q/)*** for code.which is not coming at the end of the page.Footer comes before some other divs gets finished its data.

I expect Master footer as the lastone as footer but it appears before right and left divs.

```
CSS :

#main
{
    margin:auto;
    width:90%;
    background-color:#b0e0e6;
    text-align: center;
}
#header
{
    margin:auto;
    height:20px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#footer
{
    margin:auto;
    height:100px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#content
{
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
}
#left
{
    float : left;
    width:20%;
    background-color:pink;
    display: inline-block; 
}
#middle
{
    width:60%;
    background-color:white;
    float : left;
    display: inline-block; 
}
#right
{
    width:20%;
    background-color:green;
    float : right;
    display: inline-block; 
}


#master-head
{
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#b0e0e6;
    text-align: center;
}
#master-foot
{
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#b0e0e6;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="master-head">Master Header</div>
<div id="main">main
 <div id="header">header</div>
           <div id="content">
             <div id="left">left
             1<br> 2<br> 3<br>   4<br>1<br> 1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br>11<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br>   1<br>
            <!-- 1<br> 2<br> 3<br>   4<br>1<br> 1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br>11<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br>   1<br>-->
             1<br></div>
             <div id="middle">middle</div>
             <div id="right">right
              1<br> 2<br> 3<br>  4<br>1<br> 1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br>11<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br>   1<br>
             <!-- 11<br> 2<br> 3<br>     4<br>1<br> 1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br>11<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br> 1<br>   1<br>-->
             </div>
           </div>
          <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
<div id="master-foot">Master Footer</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for #footer --

```
#footer
{
/* margin:auto; */
height:100px;
background-color:yellow;
margin-bottom: 0px;
clear: both;
}
```

for #master-foot --

```
#master-foot
{
/* margin:auto; */
background-color:#b0e0e6;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 0px;
clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a `clear: both`:

```
#master-foot
{
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#b0e0e6;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `clear: both;` in `#footer`.

Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/hjEfv/

Answer (score 1):

you are using the float on css which means the floated elements will be removed from the normal sequence of alignment.